# Grouping massive nested json by array values

Tags: php, arrays, json, grouping

I have a big json data that looks like this:

```
{
   1: {
      1: {
         1: [
           1, 2, 3
         ],
         2: [
           3, 4
         ]
      },
      2: {
          1: [
            1, 2, 3
          ],
          2: [
            3, 4
          ]
         }
    }
}
```

Ideally that json would group as something like `{1: {"1,2": {"1": [1,2,3], "2:" [3,4]}}}`
Json is around 15-25k lines. Keys are consistent, but values are not. Is there any sane way to do this?

Comment: _"Keys are consistent"_ - I assume by that you mean, the _structure_ is? Always four "levels" deep?

Comment: So if the _first_ `[1, 2, 3]` was `[4, 5, 6]` instead - then the result should be `{"1":{"1":{"1":[4,5,6]},"2":{"1":[1,2,3]},"1,2":{"2":[3,4]}}}`?

Comment: @CBroe pretty much yes. i want to group it by either last "level" key, or third if possible. and yes, its always 4 levels deep and keys (as for 1,2,3 and etc all possible values are known beforehand)

Comment: just to add a bit of context: i generate this large json to run tests on it for sanity checks in cases some code changes. now i want to generate some sort of a doc file that would be much easiser to navigate and read for non-dev staff. it has a lot of same values, so i thought i could group them by same values and then generate either MD or html out of it.

Comment: This is not clear enough, it's a big json, I don't think this is the only situation. What if there is a `3:[1,2,3]`? What if there are more nodes? This question is more about how to design navigation than grouping.

Comment: @shingo then it would add up to let's say `"2,3": [1, 2, 3]`